# How can i prepend to a dicts keys and format it to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i have a dict as below:

```
dict = {'settings': {'start_dt': "'201901'",
  'end_dt': "'202104'",
  'schema': 'blob'
 }}
```

i would like to achieve the following:

```
"SET start_dt = '201901';SET end_dt = '202104';SET schema = blob;"
```

i tried the below but it is not really what i am after

```
  elem = []
    for k,v in dictt['settings'].items():
        strings = ('SET '+k+' ='+v  )
        print(str('SET ')+k+' ='+v  )
        elem.append(strings)
```

["SET start_dt ='201901'", "SET end_dt ='202104'", 'SET schema =blob']

how can i achieve desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below, I seem to get a similar output to your desired. (`f-string`)

```
stringFormat = ""
for k,v in dict['settings'].items():
    stringFormat+=f'SET {k} = {v};'
```

output

```
"SET start_dt = '201901';SET end_dt = '202104';SET schema = blob;"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.join`:

```
d = {'settings': {'start_dt': "'201901'", 'end_dt': "'202104'", 'schema': 'blob'}}
r = ''.join(f'SET {a} = {b};' for a, b in d['settings'].items())
```

Output:

```
"SET start_dt = '201901';SET end_dt = '202104';SET schema = blob;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! You just need `join` on your `elem`: `";".join(elem)`. (However, there are more efficient ways to get it as shown in the other answers.)